# How to load data.json file - unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simplejson

I have data in .json file.

My json contains data like this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R8dh.png)

I am looking for ways to parse it in c#.
Hope everybody help please

Comment: The keyword you want to use in your searches is "deserialization". Also, please include any code or data in your question as text rather than images, because search engines and screenreaders can't read images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) make a c# class structure that mirrors the json data and call JsonUtility.FromJson
2. [using Newtonsoft.Json;](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm) you can deserialize it without creating a helper structure with JsonConvert.Deserialize

Comment: you can code in c# . I really do not understand