# how to read json string using url in unity?

Tags: php, json, unity-game-engine

I'm making some communication between PHP server and Unity. Unity sends to PHP some information and PHP response with a JSON string but I couldn't make Unity read it as JSON. It recognize it as string..

Here's the code

Unity :

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(GetInfo());
}

[System.Serializable]
public class jsonDataClass
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Status
{
    public string health { get; set; }
    public string speed { get; set; }
    public bool boolean { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerator GetInfo()
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://example.com/example.php"))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            var c = JsonUtility.ToJson(www.downloadHandler.text);
            Status loaded = JsonUtility.FromJson<Status>(c);
            Debug.Log(c);
            Debug.Log(loaded.connection);
        }
    }
}
```

output :
[image]

I tried using normal string to make sure it's not because var also tried to print the result normally :

```
string c = JsonUtility.ToJson(www.downloadHandler.text);
            Debug.Log( "\n" + www.downloadHandler.text);
            Status loaded = JsonUtility.FromJson<Status>(c);
            Debug.Log( "\n" + c);
            Debug.Log(loaded.connection);
```

the results :
[image]

print normally :
[image]

finally using FromJson :
[image]

php code :

```
$results['status'] = array(
        'health' => '0',
        'speed' => '0',
        'boolean' => false
        );
        $json = json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
        echo $json;
```

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1473952/how-to-write-and-read-json-in-unity.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71411515/how-to-load-data-json-file-unity

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie I tried what you sent me, worked as string and still string also, unity couldn't read it shows me null

Comment: do : `$json = json_encode($results);echo $json;` and see

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie same shows null

Comment: I have no idea about unity. I just search and send you the link for help. I hope some one will help you shoertly

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Unity's JSON utility needs fields, not properties. And then you were reading the JSON text, and trying to convert that to JSON .. ?

You rather want to use [`FromJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html) in order to convert the received JSON into your c# class

This should fix it for you:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class jsonDataClass
{
    public Status status;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Status
{
    public string health;
    public string speed;
    public bool boolean;
}

private IEnumerator GetInfo ()
{
    using var www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://example.com/example.php");
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning ($"Error: {www.error}");
        yield break;
    }
   
    var text = www.downloadHandler.text;
    Debug.Log($"JSON: {text}");
    var loaded = JsonUtility.FromJson<jsonDataClass>(text);
    Debug.Log($"jsonDataClass.status.health: {loaded.status.health}");
}
```

Comment: thanks for explaining that, but I tried it, it still shows Null

I'm confused why it showing null, I tried also to make local file so I can test if the json formatted wrong, even with local json file to unity still getting NULL

Comment: @ALQAWSI what does the console say after "JSON: ... " does it show you valid JSON data?